# How to handle French character in Oracle insert statement

Tags: oracle, single-quotes

```
Insert into mytable (English_Name, French_Name)
Values('Contact Center', 'Centre d'appels')
```

This would not work since the special French Character **`d'`**.

Could someone help me?

Comment: There is no such special character. Those are **two** characters: the simple Latin letter `d` and a single-quote. And the only problem is the single-quote; if you must hard-code it, you must type TWO single-quotes to get a single one in the output. (Note: two single-quote characters, not one double-quote character!)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the single-quote character, since single-quote has special meaning - it is used to indicate the beginning and the end of a hard-coded text literal.

Simplest: you need to use TWO single-quote characters to generate one such character in the output (in this case: in the value stored in the table).

Cleaner: Use the q-quote mechanism (google for the term, if you had not heard of it before). Like this:

```
insert ... values ( ... , q'[Centre d'appels]')
```

Notice `q'[` for opening and `]'` for closing the text literal.